# How do I figure out the contents of doujinshi?

Tags: resources, doujinshi

I have been to Japan and saw all these doujinshi manga which all look really interesting just by their cover. But how do Japanese people actually figure out the content of these books? There is no plot written anywhere, and you generally cannot open them.

For example, I have been reading 孤独のグルメ (Kodoku no Gurume) and I saw doujinshi based on it. Should I think "the manga was good so let's try this version"? Or is there somewhere to look at to find out the content?

Does it work only by word-of-mouth or are there any resources on the internet we can check to have more information on the different authors and their doujinshi?

Comment: There's no true and tried method for picking doujinshi. The very best ones are the hardest to find as word tends to spread by word of mouth, much like any type of fan fiction. Sometimes the more well-known circles release teasers online, but most other times people go off their previous works to gauge is a particular circle's doujinshi will be good or not. As with any fan fiction, it's not a matter of the original work, but rather the skill of the doujinshi author that's determine whether a particular doujin will be good or not.

Comment: From watching anime about otaku (lol), I guess con-goers in general have known about the circles and their works, probably also what they are going to publish, so they just buy the book without needing to view the content. That's for the more popular circles. As for new/less known circles, I think you can read the doujin right at their tables.

Comment: Most regular manga are also shrink-wrapped in Japanese bookstores, to prevent people from basically using the bookstore as a library (立ち読み). (You probably know this, but others may not.)

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ is there any resources to find the "well-known circles" ? Any chart web site based on their sales maybe ?

Answer (score -2):

It might be a simple matter of H-service, so what matters the most is the art. Something like storyline is trivial in most of the H-works in Japan as I would say. That's why, the business focuses only on gaining money.

Comment: Doujinshi is not just H-content. However, as long as you are on a Q&A based website, please consider developping your answers. Otherwise, just leave a comment instead of answerinig the question.

Comment: roger that!!!!!!